# How insert slash in mysql DB after addslashes()

Tags: php, mysql, addslashes

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root')
    OR die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('autos') or die('no db');
$bookName = "O'relly";
$user = addslashes($bookName);

$query = "INSERT INTO makes VALUES(null, '{$user}')";
mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());

var_dump($user);

?>
```

Var dump output is string 'O\'relly' (length=8)
But in DB stored as 'O'relly

Looks like Mysql strip slashes before insert in DB. It's true?

Comment: What did you think the point of `addslashes` was? It would be rather pointless if it didn't make a difference to the database. Despite that, it is still rather pointless as it isn't adequate protection. If you are going to use manual escaping, use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), but you really should use [something that gives you bound paramaters](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Answer (score 1):

SQL doesn't strip the backslash, it interprets it (properly) when parsing your command. Without the slash, SQL would see

```
INSERT INTO makes VALUES(null, 'O'relly')
```

which is the string 'O' followed by a syntax error. (Or worse: this can be exploited for the dread "sql injection attack").

In short, this is working as intended.

Comment: Ok, but if I added 'O\'relly' in DB will be O'relly

Comment: Yes, that's what it's meant to do. Why don't you tell us what you *want* to add to the database, and we can tell you how to do it.